# Toggle (show/hide) a sub menu with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am developing a site where I can NOT use jQuery (please, no comments on how good is it, it's prohibited) and I need to reproduce something like .toggle() just for show/hide a div with a class.

I've a group of boxes with a arrow, this arrow can expand a submenu. Let's see an example:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-utils">
        <a href="#" class="up">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

    <h2>Example case</h2>

    <div class="box-submenu hidden">
        <ul />
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that click on the `<a />` inside the `<div class="box-utils" />` shows/hide the box-submenu class. When it's hidden, the `<a />` needs to have class="down", when it's not hidden it needs to be class="up". This also needs to work with more than one case in the same page.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a toggle function like the one below, provide an id attribute on your DIV (call it box-submenu or something) and call the function from your anchor, and use the ID to lookup whatever you want to hide/show.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("box-submenu");
    var link = document.getElementById("linkId");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        link.className = "down";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        link.className = "up";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: I assume that the `displayText` id refers to the anchor tag? Also, your answer doesn't handle the requirement of changing the class (rather than the text) of the anchor.

Comment: No until 3 minutes! :P There is a easy way to handle events not intrusive? So I've not to use onclick="" on the `<a />`? Thank you!

Comment: If you can't use a framework like jQuery, you'll need to go with the onClick attribute on the anchor.